# Catch2 - undefined reference to

Tags: c++, testing, undefined-reference, catch-unit-test

I'm testing my project using Catch2 as library. I followed every step in the Catch doc, but when I run the tests I get the following error:

`CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/IntegerIntervalTest.cpp.o: in function "____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0()":
/home/davide/cpp-project/tests/IntegerIntervalTest.cpp:8: undefined reference to "domain::IntegerAbstractInterval<int, int>::IntegerAbstractInterval(int, int)"`

and this error repeates for every method call in the test "class".

CMakeLists:

```
PROJECT(cpp_project)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.5)
INCLUDE(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++14 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
IF (COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS("-std=c++14")
ELSE ()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support.")
ENDIF ()


set(BASE_SRCS src/Bound.cpp src/Bound.hpp src/Infinity.cpp src/Infinity.hpp src/AbstractInterval.cpp src/AbstractInterval.hpp
        src/UndefinedOperationException.hpp src/IntegerAbstractInterval.cpp src/IntegerAbstractInterval.hpp src/FloatingPointAbstractInterval.cpp
        src/FloatingPointAbstractInterval.hpp)
ADD_COMPILE_OPTIONS("-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wpedantic" "-Werror" )
ADD_LIBRARY(cpp-project ${BASE_SRCS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(libs/variant/include)


set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin)
set(CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/catch)
add_library(Catch INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(Catch INTERFACE ${CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(TEST_SRCS tests/InfinityTest.cpp tests/IntegerIntervalTest.cpp)
add_executable(tests ${BASE_SRCS} ${TEST_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(tests Catch)
```

and this is the test file `IntegerIntervalTest.cpp`:

```
#include "../src/IntegerAbstractInterval.hpp"
#include "../libs/catch2/catch.hpp"

using namespace domain;


TEST_CASE("Operations on IntegerInterval instances", "[IntegerAbstractInterval]") {
    IntegerAbstractInterval<int, int> i(0,1);
    IntegerAbstractInterval<Infinity, Infinity> ii(Infinity('-'), Infinity('+'));
    IntegerAbstractInterval<Infinity, int> iii(Infinity('-'), 5);
    IntegerAbstractInterval<int, Infinity> iv(0, Infinity('+'));
    IntegerAbstractInterval<int, int> v(-1,1);

    SECTION("Sum operations") {
        auto res1 = i + v;
        REQUIRE(res1.getLowerBound() == Bound(-1));
        REQUIRE(res1.getUpperBound() == Bound(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like one of those "Why templates should be defined only in header files" issues.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/495056/7699037) might help.

Comment: Where do you `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN`?

Comment: In another test file, which works (does not use any template)

Comment: Let me elaborate on @VTT's comment: where do you specify the `IntegerAbstractInterval` template? Do you use explicit instantiations? If answers are "I specify signatures in `.h` and implement in `.cpp`" and "I do not[ know what that is]", then that's your problem: implement templates in the header.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm trying this way.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by firstly defining the `#define` and then the `#include`:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
```

[image]

[A nice tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/03/to-catch-a-clion) on setting up and using [`Catch2`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) is provided by `JetBrains` for [`CLion`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download) IDE.